# Here Maps Reverse Geocoding doesnot retrieve Postal Code Information

Tags: reverse-geocoding, here-api

We are using HERE Maps Reverse Geocoding API and facing an issue that the postal code is not been retrieved. I would like to know if we can retrieve the postal code by sending across additional parameters. A Sample API call is mentioned below:-

[http://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?app_id=[app_id]&app_code=[app_code]&gen=4&prox=1.3117599,103.8195267,100&mode=retrieveAddresses&addressattributes=hnr,str,cty,dis,sta,ctr,pst,add&additionaldata=PreserveUnitDesignators,true&locationattributes=ar,mr,mv,ad,ai](http://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.xml?app_id=%5bapp_id%5d&app_code=%5bapp_code%5d&gen=4&prox=1.3117599,103.8195267,100&mode=retrieveAddresses&addressattributes=hnr,str,cty,dis,sta,ctr,pst,add&additionaldata=PreserveUnitDesignators,true&locationattributes=ar,mr,mv,ad,ai)

Please let us know if we are missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: indeed the docs are saying that the pst would be the one that needs to be there. anyway, it also says that "On by default: All except addressLines." so you could leave the whole addressattributes out. Also try different modes to see if there is any real difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not an issue with the API itself, it is a matter of the quality of the underlying data in **Singapore**.

You can make a reverse geocode request and obtain PostCode data if it exists with the following request

[http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&prox=LAT,LONG,RADIUS&mode=retrieveAddresses](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=13.0433,80.2516,100&mode=retrieveAddresses)

replacing the fields as necessary. In the response there is `matchQuality` attribute which defines which fields have been returned with confidence.

I tried to reverse geocode a few random locations and here is what I found:

- [Chennai, India](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=13.0433,80.2516,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) - contains Postcode, `MatchQuality.PostalCode = 1`
- [Nashville, United States](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=36.1498,-86.7616,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) - contains Postcode, `MatchQuality.PostalCode = 1`
- [Cape Town, South Africa](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=-33.9333,18.4871,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) - contains Postcode, `MatchQuality.PostalCode = 1`
- [Hong Kong](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=22.3273,114.1658,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) - doesn't contain postcode, `MatchQuality.PostalCode` not present.
- [Singapore](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=1.3117599,103.8195267,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) - doesn't contain postcode, `MatchQuality.PostalCode` not present.

You will only be able to retrieve a postcode where the data exists. Indeed if you try somewhere really remote like [Fiji](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=-18.1298,178.4592,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) or the [Falkland Islands](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=5&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&prox=-51.7208,-57.8366,100&mode=retrieveAddresses) you can find locations where the geocoder will only confidently return data at the city or even country level (which makes sense in these out-of-the-way places)